# Simplest way to connect a single strain gauge to HX711

Tags: strain-gage

I want to make a machine end-stop trigger using a strain gauge in a location where regular end-stop simply wouldn't fit - a moving part pushing against end-of-track bar, detect the bar is under strain, send end-stop triggered signal. Due to geometry and space constraint, I can only use a single strain gauge.

I don't need accuracy at all, I don't care about the absolute value readout or signal gradient slopes - all slow changes, small vibrations, thermal expansion and such, this all will be filtered away in software. A firm push will be detected and cause the microcontroller to activate an optocoupler, its output lines connected to endstop trigger terminal.

I have some BF350-3AA strain gauges and a HX711 module, this kind:

[image]
<sup>[image from arduino forums](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/reducing-current-consumption-of-hx711/566716)</sup>
[image]
<sup>[easyeda.com schematic](https://easyeda.com/modules/HX711-Load-cell-module_0729e7892c20462cb1fb685384873adc)</sup>

The geometry constraints mean full and half bridge configs are right out. (I mean, I could use more strain gauges and leave them hanging in the air, somehow I don't think that's a good idea). I could go with quarter-bridge for sure, but I'm asking - maybe there is an even simpler way?

Comment: And a bit more specific, I assume you want to connect just a single strain gauge to an HX-711 ?

Comment: @Nedd as specified in the body. Unless connecting 3 more and leaving them to flutter in the wind is preferred.

Comment: Would 3 standard fixed resistors and a single strain gauge be acceptable?

Comment: @SF. - Hi, To comply with the site rule on [referencing](/help/referencing), please [edit] the question & add the PDF / video / webpage name and its link for the source of each copied image. TY

Comment: @SamGibson like that?